# Spring - user log-in through custom controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, authentication

I have a login controller that checks if user login&password is valid through database connection, like this:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String validateLogin(@ModelAttribute("form") LoginForm form, ModelMap model) {
    String out = "";
    if (userDAO.login(form.getLogin(), form.getPassword())) {
        out += "Successful log in!";
    } else {
        out += "Log in failed: no such login/password pair found.";
    }
    model.addAttribute("message", out);
    return "loginresult";
}
```

How do I create a user session for user who have correctly submitted login&password? I tried Spring Security native methods but they do not seem to work correctly.

Comment: Why do you need to reinvent wheel? Spring security is good for the things. Use it and post a question if you have some problems with this.

Comment: This might get you started: http://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/